# google-cloud-run quarkus Keyloack

Tags: keycloak, quarkus, google-cloud-run

I deploy Keycloak under GCE. I succesfully reach the /auth url.
Now I try to deploy a secured microservice under cloud run. This microservice must communicate with keycloak to check authentification
This microservice is a quarkus application. Properties are :

```
# Configuration file
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=https://[url]:[port]/auth/realms/quarkus
quarkus.oidc.client-id=backend-service
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=secret
quarkus.http.cors=true

# Enable Policy Enforcement
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=true

# Disables policy enforcement for a path
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.1.path=/api/public
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.1.enforcement-mode=DISABLED
```

At the last step, when cloud build have to deploy and run the native image, i get an error :

```
Caused by: io.quarkus.oidc.OIDCException: OIDC server is not available at the 'quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url' URL. Please make sure it is correct. Note it has to end with a realm value if you work with Keycloak, for example: 'https://localhost:8180/auth/realms/quarkus'
```

Can someone can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Is `quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url` your Keycloak server URL? In other words, is the Keycloak console reachable in your browser at https://quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url/auth?

Comment: Yes of course i can connect to the console. Realm is present too

Comment: Possibly related to https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/9155

Comment: Do you also have a confidential client created in that realm called `backend-service` with a client secret of `secret`?

Comment: Yes realm exist with theses properties ... I upload sample realm from tutorial. Cf https://quarkus.io/guides/security-keycloak-authorization. Juste create native image and deploy it in CloudRun

Comment: Ok i fix the issue. url was wrong... i check it so many times....

Comment: Can you please post an answer showing how you fixed it? This can help other users in the community find your answer more quickly. Thanks @anthony44.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix this issue by updating https://[url]:[port]/auth/realms/quarkus to https://[url]/auth/realms/quarkus.
No port value !